# CIFS share mounting but not able to read contents

Tags: linux, cifs

I have cifs share coming out of an Isilon server. Let's say the share name is //server/path/subdir1/subdir1-1

Here - the account im using to mount, has full read/write permissions (in the isilon server as well) to the above share. However, while I'm able to mount the path, when i do ls, i get

```
ls: reading directory .: Permission denied
```

I tried going up one step at a time with the share, i was able to read from //server/path, but not from subdir1. All the permissions are correct in the windows side. What do I look at further?

P.S.: Im using kerberos to mount the share.

Answer (score 0):

It was the permission issue in windows side. Inheritence was not set on sub folders.